# Convert a irr::c8 to a wchar_t*

Tags: c++, type-conversion, wchar-t, irrlicht

I'm making a 3D environment, and I want to make it so that when you pass the crosshair over an object, some text with its description pops up. But I have this really annoying string format thing in the way.

```
  info.setText(CollMan->getSceneNodeFromScreenCoordinatesBB(blah)->getName());
```

info being the text object, and getSceneNodeblahblah->getName being the description that I want.

This doesnt work, because setText wants a wchar_t* and getName() provides an irr::c8.
.c_str() doesn't seem to help whatsoever.

How can I get these two to play nice?

Comment: More info. What’s the type of `info`? Is it an Irrlicht object as well? Otherwise, why doesn’t it accept `irr::c8`? That would both be easier and a better design. `wchar_t` in general should be avoided.

Comment: info is a irr::gui::IGUIStaticText. I'd love to avoid wchar_t, i just dont know how to make setText accept something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading the docs correctly you ought to be able to do it by converting it to an irr::core::stringw first as follows:

```
info.setText( irr::core::stringw( CollMan->getSceneNodeFromScreenCoordinatesBB(blah)->getName() ).c_str() );
```

Comment: @MagicAxis:  I found the docs by literally doing a search for irr::c8 ;)

Comment: LOL I swear I googled that too, and all i found was a somewhat related forum post and a definition of a c8! Aah well, cheers :3

Comment: @Magicaxis:  I did have to do a bit more searching around the docs but you get used to finding "what ought to be there" when you've dealt with enough APIs ;)